# Printer takes too long to start printing

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have 3 different broadband modems connected on an unmanaged D link switch. We have users plugged onto this unmanaged switch who use desired modem gateway

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.2.1

to connect to internet.
The printer Canon LBP2900 is connected via USB to one of the systems and shared with other users on the network.
The problem is, when the users on the network issue the print command, it takes about 1 or 2 minutes to actually start printing.
There are no files under `system32/spool/printers`.
I have print spooler service set to `Automatic` on all systems.
Spool settings on printer is set to `Start printing after last page is Spooled`.

Earlier, did the print commands from an other network than that of printer associated system, use to come through quickly. Now are the prints from the same network coming out after a long time.

I still can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Why do you have it set to start printing after the last page is spooled?  Changing that to start printing immediately would make a huge difference, I would think.

Comment: Hi Bill, I tried both the other options, start printing immediately and Print directly to the printer but to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked Canon's web site for updated printer drivers?  I'm afraid that's my only other suggestion.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded latest driver and installed the printer on other system than it was. Maybe I'll have to reboot the Switch. Thanks.

Comment: Does the printing speed change if you host the printer on a different computer?

Comment: I hosted the printer on different system, with all other systems in the same network i.e.,(192.168.3.1) the printer works just fine. But when i issue print from other network say 192.168.2.1 then it takes quite some time to get the print. I think its the disadvantage of using an unmanaged switch.